# Will my car pass emissions if all monitors pass scanner except EVAP monitor

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, corolla, cel, emissions

I had toyota remove a P code off my 2010 1.8L corolla after a repair. I need to pass emissions in Arizona in the next 2 weeks. I went to AZ and they let me borrow the scanner so I plugged it and ALl monitors were in a ready state except the eva (evap) monitor. Will my car pass emissions as is? Please see photos. On the Arizona ADQ website it says “ Model year 2001 and newer vehicles may not have more than one “not-ready” monitor.“ This does not specify which one of the monitors can be in a not ready state. For me it is the EVAP monitor which I read can be in a not ready state, but is this valid? Also the CEL is off. [image: scanner image 1]. [image: scanner image 2] [image: scanner image 3] [image: scanner image 4]. [image: scanner image 5]

Comment: In Texas USA, you can have 1 monitor incomplete.

Comment: I went to get my car tested yesterday here in Arizona and it passes even with EVAP not in ready state.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It won't pass if the testing involves looking at the OBDII readiness indicators. More than likely it just hasn't completed its drive cycle. For the EVAP, your fuel has to be between 1/4 and 3/4 full ... if above or below this, it most likely will not complete. It should complete during the two week period, though, as long as there aren't any issues with the system (if it wasn't an issue before, more than likely there won't be an issue now).

Comment: So essentially I just need to drive more? Maybe go through a full drive cycle?

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting. If you have two weeks until you need to do the testing, it should most likely complete. Just ensure, like I said, it is between 1/4 and 3/4 or it will most likely not complete.